# Go back to a previous git commit

Tags: git

Consider the following git log:

```
commit 6c7bd597252a1c9b9fe3ddbac1febbfa62b0f06a
Author: ...
Date:   Sat Oct 15 16:22:16 2016 +0200

    mess2

commit 9c9a8198df44d8efa4ee22c2f877e9fc6a16f27b
Author: ..
Date:   Fri Oct 14 15:52:34 2016 +0200

    mess1

commit 43a07c068d5c8d7879a60450a28c05c980ef34de
Author: ..
Date:   Wed Oct 12 11:52:09 2016 +0200

    v0.6.0
```

It might be too simple: I'd like to discard `mess1` and `mess2` and carry on just with commit `v0.6.0`. How can I do this?

I tried the following: `git checkout 43a07c0..`
but it seems that the files in my directory are not the ones from the desired commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the second most highly voted question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git

Comment: If in fact *"it seems that the files in my directory are not the ones from the desired commit"* then you are likely mistaken about what was committed in the subsequent messes. Use `git show <commit SHA>` or `git diff <SHA>^..HEAD` to ensure you're not discarding something you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing mess1 and mess2, you can

```
git reset --hard 43a07c068d5c8d7879a60450a28c05c980ef34de
```